# Reducing size of error bar caps in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I am trying to plot a graph with the following code:

```
p<-ggplot(averagedf, aes(x=Time, y=average,col=Strain)) + 
        geom_line() +
        geom_point()+
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=average-sem,ymax=average+sem))+
        theme_classic()+
        theme(legend.position = "none")
```

And the graph looks like this- which is all fine, except that the caps(?) of the error bars are too wide:[First plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TUVJ.png)

In order to reduce the width of the caps, I set width to 2, but now the caps are not centred around the the vertical line of the error bar. Does anyone have any idea on how to change the size of the caps without messing up its position?

```
p<-ggplot(averagedf, aes(x=Time, y=average,col=Strain)) + 
        geom_line() +
        geom_point()+
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=average-sem,ymax=average+sem,width=2))+
        theme_classic()+
        theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[Second plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iq7uG.png)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if that's just an artifact of the resolution of the graphics render. Without your exact data, it's hard to reproduce your exact plot, but with a similar example using an included R dataset, I don't have this issue.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ChickWeight %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = weight, color = factor(Diet))) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line") +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.5) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! After I saved the plot as pdf, the error bar caps looked completely normal. Somehow they were only messed up when I did print(p) in R Studio.

Comment: It's weird, I've also seen this with color reproduction on rare ocasions. I have no idea what causes it, but maybe someone smarter will come along and enlighten us!